# set an interval to refresh an api after x time

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, setinterval

i have a node server that fetchs api from NASA apoc api
i want the node server to make a request evrey 24 hours and get the latest JSON
ive tried to set an interval via function and it didn't work

```js
import http from 'http';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import "./schema.mjs"
import { lastSol } from './schema.mjs';
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3001;

const server = http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
  
  
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // allow all domains to access the data
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET'); // allow get domains to access the data
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age', 2592000);  
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');  // set the content type to json

  let apiURL = 'https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=XXXX';
  
  const response = await fetch(apiURL); // fetching the data from the api
  const apod = await response.json();
  function callApiEveryCSeconds(n) {
    setInterval(apod, n * 1000);
}

callApiEveryCSeconds(1);


  res.end(JSON.stringify(callApiEveryCSeconds)); // return JSON response

});

console.log(lastSol())

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Comment: The first argument to `setInterval()` must be a function to call. `apod` is not a function, it's the response to the last fetch call.

Comment: This type of thing is generally done in the client, using `setInterval()` to call the API periodically.

Comment: For a simple task like caching json from a rate limited api I usually just check the last cache time on each request.  And if it has expired then refresh the data.  Unlike a cron job, it only updates the data when the page is actively in use.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off running the API and creating a separate worker task that fetches data from the API and stores it on a time interval.